# Calculating the peak voltage of a zener diode output

Tags: diodes, zener

I have a problem with this homework, I have to calculate the peak voltage of the output after stabilizing with a zener diode.

My Input Voltage is Vin = 5V + 0.7V*sin (2pi*f*t) with f=10kHz

My circuit is a simple regulator with no load resistor. The series resistance is 82 Ohms, Zener voltage is 3V, max. current through the diode is 33.3mA. How can I calculate the peak output ? My problem is the offset created by 5V, wouldnt the Zener voltage be reached immidiately with this configuration ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD9EsC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You seem to be missing a variable here, or is it really asking for maximum current at the output?

Comment: Its asking for the peak value of the output voltage

Comment: YOu should edit your question and click on the schematic editor and show the actual circuit just to make sure we are on the same page.

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: Your resistor will create a voltage drop. Try assuming a voltage of 3V over your zener, and see what the current through R1 is.

Comment: 1n4733 is a 5.1V zener